# Why won't my audio clips play consistently?

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to make a drum loop editor and I have a class called Sounds and a class to run my main method, which all that is used for currently is testing the Sounds class.

Here is the body of my main class:

```
private static Sounds sounds;

public static void main(String args[]){
    while(true){ //yes, i realize I shouldn't do this. it's only for testing
        sounds.play(Sounds.BASS);
        sounds.play(Sounds.CLOSED_HIHAT);
        pause(500);
        sounds.play(Sounds.CLOSED_HIHAT);
        pause(500);
        sounds.play(Sounds.SNARE);
        sounds.play(Sounds.CLOSED_HIHAT);
        pause(500);
        sounds.play(Sounds.OPEN_HIHAT);
        pause(500);
    }
}

public static void pause(long time){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(time);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

And here is my Sounds class:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class Sounds{

    static AudioClip[] sounds ={
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("bass.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("snare.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("closed hihat.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("closed hihat.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("open hihat.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("low floor tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("high floor tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("low tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("low mid tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("high mid tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("high tom.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("crash 1.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("crash 2.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("ride.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("ride bell.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("china.wav")),
        Applet.newAudioClip(Sounds.class.getResource("splash.wav"))
    };
    //index constants
    protected static int BASS=0;
    protected static int SNARE=1;
    protected static int CLOSED_HIHAT=2;
    protected static int PEDAL_HIHAT=3;
    protected static int OPEN_HIHAT=4;
    protected static int TOM1=5;
    protected static int TOM2=6;
    protected static int TOM3=7;
    protected static int TOM4=8;
    protected static int TOM5=9;
    protected static int TOM6=10;
    protected static int CRASH1=11;
    protected static int CRASH2=12;
    protected static int RIDE=13;
    protected static int RIDE_BELL=14;
    protected static int CHINA=15;
    protected static int SPLASH=16;


    public void play(int soundIndex){
        sounds[soundIndex].play();
        if(soundIndex == Sounds.CLOSED_HIHAT || soundIndex == Sounds.PEDAL_HIHAT){
            sounds[Sounds.OPEN_HIHAT].stop();
        }
        if(soundIndex == Sounds.RIDE_BELL){
            sounds[Sounds.RIDE].stop();
        }
    }       
}
```

My problem is that the sounds play, but not every single time. Often there will be a hihat just completely left out, mostly during the beats that also have a snare or bass playing as well.

If you are going to try to make your own copy of my project to try to figure out the problem, you can get a zip folder of the wav files I'm using here:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/q1iok0dji4d228w/drum_wav_files.zip

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Let everything play out and dont stop

put a few  minutes sleep at the end to let everythng play out

you need to cut the files to what exaclty is needed to play and let play all -  not have 5 minutes in the wav but want to play 2.5 - its unpredictable.

So have the files cut down to what is needed and play them all in the sequence you need.

Otherwise yu have to go to more elaborate measurement of the length of file what is needed to play how many bytes etc

Added: You can go to  AudioSystem and the javax.sound.sampled package its a bit more complicated so you need to read on that -

Comment: I can't have minutes between each beat because then the program would be virtually unusable, and I can't have the open hihat continue playing after a closed hihat or pedal hihat is played because that's just not how drums work.

Comment: i meant sleep() at the and of main so nothing is left out. the play-stop is unpredictable it could cut off depending on the runtime not the actual duration -

Comment: Are there any more reliable classes I could use for sounds instead of AudioClip? I need precision and speed to accomplish my vision for this project, because I basically want to make a complete music editor that allows for unlimited measures that can play at different tempos and have different time signatures as well as have anywhere from whole notes to 32nd notes that can be dotted or triplets.

Comment: you can go to AudioSystem javax.sound.sampled

Comment: I couldn't get the AudioSystem to work for me, but while researching it I did find out about the midi features from javax.sound, which I might be able to use instead, so thanks for pointing me in the correct general direction (javax.sound).